# How to change the default error message "Incorrect password." in the Manage Account of MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Maybe this is an easy question but I'm tired of searching for it.

I have this in the AccountViewModels.cs (this is a default MVC5 project).

```
 public class ManageUserViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }
...
```

I know this uses Data Annotations behind, but I don't know how to change the default error message when I enter the incorrect OldPassword, the default error message right now is **Incorrect password.** and I want to change it for another message, please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is simple don’t worry, go to AccountController.cs in the

```
 // POST: /Account/Manage
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
 {
```

….

Change this :

```
if (hasPassword)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
          if (result.Succeeded)
          {
               return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
          }
          else
          {
               AddErrors(result);
          }
     }
}
```

For this:

```
if (hasPassword)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
          if (result.Succeeded)
          {
               return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
          }
          else
          {
               ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Whatever message do you want to say");
          }
     }
}
```

That’s it!

EDIT: code review.